# Architecture to specify fields (including nested ones) in REST API requests

Tags: javascript, api, python-requests, rest

I tried to exhaust my research on this. Is there an existing conventional solution/architecture to specify the fields that I want for my API **GET** requests. E.g.

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/entities/fields?field1,field2[subfields-of-field2-here]
```

The solution is easy for un-nested list since I just need to pass a string of fields: `field1,field2,field3,field4` but if I further want to specify the nested fields, I'm not so sure of the direction that I want to take. So if you have any suggested solution, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of [OpenAPI/Swagger](https://swagger.io/specification/) to document it or are you looking to parse it?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. I'm more interested to parse it although the parsing side is not my issue. I'm curious if there is an existing general solution for it. Something like of a convention. Or an easier solution.

Comment: I'd argue query string parameters are not the ideal way to go about passing on desired (nested) fields. Is this something that would be open to change? Such as your endpoint(s) accepting a JSON body, in which it's much easier to define a clear hierarchy between fields

Comment: No it's not an absolute rule to pass it as string params. However, it's a GET request so I can't really pass a JSON body.